# overflow y visible not working with overflow x hidden

Tags: css, vue.js

[image]

```
.iati-list-table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

The scroll bar appears when I use overflow-visible and when i use overflowy-hidden the tooptip is croped.

how do I make in such a way that overflow x is auto and overflow y is normal(no scroll bar and tooltips are not cropped
)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to read this and figure it out.

It will help you out:-[CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue/6433475#6433475)

If you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and something other than visible for the other, the visible value is interpreted as auto.